# GString pointer memory leak

Tags: gtk, glib, gstring

I am trying to free `GString *` using `g_string_free`, pointer was allocated using `g_string_sized_new`. But valgrind gives memory leak for same.

**Example Code:**

```
Ports * function(bs_t *bs)
{
    GString *string = g_string_sized_new(PATH_MAX);
    char template[] = "/tmp/grokXXXXXX";
    Ports *rc =NULL;

    if (condition) {
        rc = (Ports *) malloc (sizeof(Ports));
        if (rc == NULL) {
            g_string_free(string, TRUE);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    if (condition_2) {
        if (!port_file(string->str, &rc->ports[0], &rc->port_valid, 
            NUM_RC_PORTS))
        {
            g_free(rc);
            rc=NULL;
        }
    }
    g_string_free(string, TRUE);
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: What’s the valgrind error message?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing calls to plain `malloc` with wrapped `g_free`,

```
 rc = (Ports *) malloc (sizeof(Ports));
    .
    .
    .
 g_free(rc);
```

Use plain or wrapped memory allocators consistently.

Comment: Your answer is not wrong (memory allocators and deallocators should always be used pairwise consistently), but since GLib 2.45.5, `g_malloc()` is equivalent to `malloc()` and `g_free()` is equivalent to `free()`, so that’s probably not the problem here.